# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, Program does not stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone I'm making **Tic-Tac-Toe Game** for school. But when al boxes are checked i need the program to stop and say: you win, you lose, or draw.

But is doesn't. when you lose or win before al 9 boxes are checked it says you won or lose.

I also get this error when all boxes are checked:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

**Code:**

```
       var button = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) button[i] = document.getElementById('canvas'+i);


    var ctx = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) ctx[i] = button[i].getContext('2d');

      var bDisabled= [];
     for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) bDisabled[i] = false;    



    var isResult = false;
    var content = [];

     function loop (x)

      {
         if(!bDisabled[x])
    {

        bDisabled[x] = true;
        button[x].style.opacity = 0.7;
        content[x] = 'x';

        button[x].style.webkitTransform="rotatey(180deg)";

        {
            ctx[x].lineWidth=3;
            ctx[x].beginPath(   );
            ctx[x].moveTo(10,10);
            ctx[x].lineTo(40,40);
            ctx[x].moveTo(40,10);
            ctx[x].lineTo(10,40);
            ctx[x].stroke();
            ctx[x].closePath();

            computerTurn();    
        }
        setTimeout(checkWinner, 1000);


    }

    }

        function computerTurn()
    {
       var r = Math.random();

      if (r < 0.1 && !bDisabled[1]) draw0Steps(1);
       else if (r < 0.2 && !bDisabled[2]) draw0Steps(2);
       else if (r < 0.3 && !bDisabled[3]) draw0Steps(3);
      else if (r < 0.4 && !bDisabled[4]) draw0Steps(4);
       else if (r < 0.5 && !bDisabled[5]) draw0Steps(5);
      else if (r < 0.6 && !bDisabled[6]) draw0Steps(6);
       else if (r < 0.7 && !bDisabled[7]) draw0Steps(7);
       else if (r < 0.8 && !bDisabled[8]) draw0Steps(8);
        else if (r < 1 && !bDisabled[9]) draw0Steps(9);
       else computerTurn();
}


     function draw0Steps(x)

{

    bDisabled[x]=true;
    button[x].style.opacity=0.7;
    content[x]='0'; 
    button[x].style.webkitTransform="rotateX(180deg)";

    setTimeout(function()
    { 
    ctx[x].beginPath();
    ctx[x].lineWidth=3;
    ctx[x].arc(25,25,17,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    ctx[x].stroke();
    ctx[x].closePath();
    }, 300);
}

        function checkWinner()
    {
         if(!isResult)
        {
              if (content[1] == 'x' && content[2] == 'x' && content[3] == 'x')                        s      howWinner('Je hebt gewonnen!');
                   else if (content[4] == 'x' && content[5] == 'x' && content[6] ==    'x') showWinner('Je hebt gewonnen!');
            else if (content[7] == 'x' && content[8] == 'x' && content[9] == 'x') showWinner('Je hebt gewonnen!');
                      else if (content[1] == 'x' && content[4] == 'x' && content[7] == 'x') showWinner('Je hebt gewonnen!');
                       else if (content[2] == 'x' && content[5] == 'x' && content[8] == 'x') showWinner('Je hebt gewonnen!');
                      else if (content[3] == 'x' && content[6] == 'x' && content[9] == 'x') showWinner('Je hebt gewonnen!');
            else if (content[1] == 'x' && content[5] == 'x' && content[9] == 'x') showWinner('Je hebt gewonnen!');
            else if (content[3] == 'x' && content[5] == 'x' && content[7] == 'x') showWinner('Je hebt gewonnen!');

            else if (content[1] == '0' && content[2] == '0' && content[3] == '0') showWinner('Je hebt verloren!');
            else if (content[4] == '0' && content[5] == '0' && content[6] == '0') showWinner('Je hebt verloren!');
            else if (content[7] == '0' && content[8] == '0' && content[9] == '0') showWinner('Je hebt verloren!');
            else if (content[1] == '0' && content[4] == '0' && content[7] == '0') showWinner('Je hebt verloren!');
            else if (content[2] == '0' && content[5] == '0' && content[8] == '0') showWinner('Je hebt verloren!');
            else if (content[3] == '0' && content[6] == '0' && content[9] == '0') showWinner('Je hebt verloren!');
            else if (content[1] == '0' && content[5] == '0' && content[9] == '0') showWinner('Je hebt verloren!');
            else if (content[3] == '0' && content[5] == '0' && content[7] == '0') showWinner('Je hebt verloren!');

            else if(

                 (content[1]=='x' || content[1]=='0')&&
                 (content[2]=='x' || content[2]=='0')&&
                 (content[3]=='x' || content[3]=='0')&&
                 (content[4]=='x' || content[4]=='0')&&
                 (content[5]=='x' || content[5]=='0')&&
                 (content[6]=='x' || content[6]=='0')&&
                 (content[7]=='x' || content[7]=='0')&&
                 (content[8]=='x' || content[8]=='0')&&
                 (content[9]=='x' || content[9]=='0')
                )
                showWinner("Gelijkspel. Speel opnieuw!");
        }



    }   

          function showWinner(x)
    {
       alert(x);
       isResult=true;

   }
```

Comment: The `computerTurn()` function calls itself under some condition. If it does, nothing will change and it will call itself again. That's what causes the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" problem.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for your'e reply! Do you think this is bad ? and does this effect that the code is NOT saying that it is drawn?

Comment: Yes it is bad. It means that your code does not work.

Comment: You could debug your code before asking this question. Use the F12 key in your Browser.